# nHibernate QueryOver performing a SubSelect to load a collection instead of a Join

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Ok I'm trying to load some many to many collections on my User object (Followers, Following, PostLikes, CommentLikes). However when I perform a Left Join on these collections using QueryOver it returns more records than should be returned.

I looked at the SQL with SQL Profiler and it seems as instead of just producing 4 joins it is producing 8 creating a somewhat looping query. This is my current query.

```
User userAlias = null;
        User followingAlias = null;
        User followersAlias = null;
        Post postLikesAlias = null;
        Comment commentLikesAlias = null;

        var entity = Session.QueryOver(() => userAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => userAlias.Followers, () => followersAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => userAlias.Following, () => followingAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => userAlias.PostLikes, () => postLikesAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => userAlias.CommentLikes, () => commentLikesAlias)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        ReleaseCurrentSession();

        return entity;
```

Anyway when I do not selectively load things and use eager loading through my fluent mappings. The collections load perfectly. Again I looked at Sql Profiler and it seems to execute a separate select query for each collection. Is there a way I can do this using QueryOver instead of using joins? I know in your mappings you can specify FetchTypes, but when I do this and just use .Fetch(x => x.Followers) etc it still produces a join!

Thanks in advanced,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as the end of your query.

```
 .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

or

```
 .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
 .List();
```

and accessing the first item.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. NHibernate doesn't issue separate queries for collections. So querying a collection is easy when you're only dealing with a single collection off the root.

You can use CreateMultiCriteria() to create separate queries batched together and transform them into a single result.

Alternatively i believe you can also use .Future() on each of the queries so they are batched together, NH will use first level cache to grab the collections.